# ExtJS - How can I manipulate existing grid with javascript?

Tags: javascript, extjs, automation, web

I am using a web-automation tool against a site that utilizes an ExtJS grid, and would like to run some JavaScript that would simulate the 'onlick' event of a row... When I fire a regular onclick event on the respective div tags, nothing happens.

I did an 'Ext.version' and got 2.2, so I looked up the Ext 2.2 API here: http://extjs.edspencer.net/extjs/docs/ but I cannot really make sense of it. I am not concerned with creating a new grid but manipulating an existing one.. Any ideas?

Comment: Which automation tool are you using?

Comment: SWAT, http://ulti-swat.wikispaces.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look at events on the GridPanel. There's a `rowclick` event. You can then apply a listener to the grid, either in the grid config:

```
new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    ...
    listeners: {
        rowclick: function() {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
});
```

Or after the fact:

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    id: 'fooGrid'
});

Ext.getCmp('fooGrid').addListener('click', function(){
    // do some stuff
})
```

But if you want to fire the onclick event, as you stated, do the following:

```
var rowIndex = 5;
var grid = Ext.getCmp('fooGrid')

grid.fireEvent('rowclick', grid, rowIndex)
```

Source, the Observable object. Almost everything inherits from Observable in ExtJS 2:

http://extjs.edspencer.net/extjs/docs/#Ext.util.Observable

Comment: Should 'fooGrid' be the actual ID of the grid we are trying to manipulate? And if so, what tag is the correct ID in?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about the HTML tag when using ExtJS components. If you access the objects through the components, everything works better. Some IDs don't end up on the page, but in Ext's ComponentManager.

Comment: Edited my response to better answer your question. See the end.

Comment: Yep, I think using fireEvent() is probably a better approach than fiddling with the selection model.

Answer (score 0):

I think @WattsInABox is spot-on there with the way to pick the individual component, but you are after 'triggering' the click event, not adding a listener.

ExtJS kind of exists in its own abstracted bubble so rather then triggering the DOM event 'click' event, what you want to do is trigger the SELECTION of a particular row. The code for selecting the first row will look like this:

```
Ext.getCmp('fooGrid').getSelectionModel().selectRow(0);
```

With 'fooGrid' being the id of the grid you are intending to trigger the action on.

Comment: You're totally right that I misunderstood the question. You're answer doesn't quite get it either, but I'll edit mine and see if we can nail this. :)